# vba div angular selecting option

Tags: vba, angular

I need to select a option "I want select to this".  And I tried the following code, but I am getting error message that object required. Here is one of the example of element I tried

```
ie.document.getelementbyid("sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp).option(1)
ie.document.getelementbyid("sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp).option(0)
or 
ie.document.getelementbyid("element.incident.u_im_reporter_grp").focus
ie.document.getelementbyid("element.incident.u_im_reporter_grp).click
```

website source code in the comment reply if you cannot see all it below.

```
<div class="section-content" id="ID123" glide="true">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="vsplit col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group is-required" id="element.incident.u_im_reporter_grp">
                <div id="label.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                      nowrap="true" type="reference" data-type="label"
                      choice="1">
                    <label class=" col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4
                           control-label" dir="ltr"
                           onclick="return labelClicked(this);"
                           for="sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp">
                         <span title="" class="required-marker
                               label_description" 
                               id="status.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                               aria-label="Mandatory - must be populated before Submit"
                               data-original-title="Mandatory - must be populated before Submit" oclass=""
                               mandatory="true">
                         </span>
                         <span title="" class="label-text"
                               data-original-title="" data-html="false">
                           Reporter Group
                         </span>
                     </label>
                 </div>
```

```
                 <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls">
                     <input name="sys_original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                            id="sys_original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                            type="hidden">
                     <input name="incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                            class="direction:ltr"
                            id="incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                            onchange="onChange('incident.u_im_reporter_grp')"
                            type="hidden" value="" mandatory="true">
                     <input name="sys_display.original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                             id="sys_display.original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                            type="hidden" value="">
                     <select name="sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                             class="form-control"
                             id="sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                             style="direction: ltr;"
                              onchange="onSelChange('sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp');
                             updateAndFlip(this, 'incident.u_im_reporter_grp');">
                         <option value="">-- None --</option>
                         <option value="random value">I want select to this</option>
                     </select>
                     <input name="sys_display.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                            id="sys_display.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"
                            type="hidden" value="">

                     <script language="javascript">var select = gel('sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp');
```

Comment: It is not `getelementbyid` it's `getElementById`

Comment: <div class="section-content" id="ID123" glide="true"><div class="row"><div class="vsplit col-sm-6"><div class="form-group is-required" id="element.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"><div id="label.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" nowrap="true" type="reference" data-type="label" choice="1"><label class=" col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label" dir="ltr" onclick="return labelClicked(this);" for="sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"><span title="" class="required-marker label_description" id="status.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" aria-

Comment: label="Mandatory - must be populated before Submit" data-original-title="Mandatory - must be populated before Submit" oclass="" mandatory="true"></span><span title="" class="label-text" data-original-title="" data-html="false">Reporter Group</span></label></div><div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls"><input name="sys_original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp"

Comment: id="sys_original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" type="hidden"><input name="incident.u_im_reporter_grp" class="direction:ltr" id="incident.u_im_reporter_grp" onchange="onChange('incident.u_im_reporter_grp')" type="hidden" value="" mandatory="true"><input name="sys_display.original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" id="sys_display.original.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" type="hidden" value=""><select name="sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" class="form-control"

Comment: id="sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" style="direction: ltr;" onchange="onSelChange('sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp'); updateAndFlip(this, 'incident.u_im_reporter_grp');"><option value="">-- None --</option><option value="random value">I want select to this</option></select><input name="sys_display.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" id="sys_display.incident.u_im_reporter_grp" type="hidden" value=""><script language="javascript">var select = gel('sys_select.incident.u_im_reporter_grp');

Comment: You need to add that scripts in your question. Edit your question with that.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, that just my typing but VBA will correct it to getElementById if I type getelementbyid

Comment: Sorry Ankit I do not know how. I added it in my original question but I think I went over the max char limit and it cut it off.  So I have to that way

Comment: You [edit] the html into your question and put it as code snippet. Use the editing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Dim a As Object
Set a = ie.document.querySelector("option[value='random value']")
a.Selected = True
```

This uses a CSS selector of `option[value='random value']`, which looks for the first element, as using `querySelector` method to apply, with tag `option`, that has attribute `value` with value of `'random value'`.

Based on your HTML in comments this would be the CSS query result:

[image: CSS query]

This .`Selected` part of the code assumes the element is selectable. I have however shown how to set the element to a variable as well.

Comment: Thanks QHarr, the page completed loaded.  I am still getting same error
Run-time error '424':
Object required
on the line Set a = ie.document.querySelector("option[value='random value']")
I did declared my object before this line.

Comment: Is the div element inside a form or iframe or frame?

Comment: Maybe mistype on my code, but it worked, Thanks QHarr

Comment: I am trying to find it,  Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Lol, I got it thanks.  That show my level of computer skill :)

Comment: We all start somewhere. You wouldn't imagine how frustrated I got with trying to put code between code tags. I nearly gave up on SO for ever because of that.

Comment: Thanks for understanding, how do to select option that next match. I can set the for loop but I don't how to select it.  You are right it is in Iframe
For x = 0 To ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelectorAll("option[value='2']").Length
    If x = 2 Then
        'what do I write in there here to selection the option
    End If
Next x

Comment: Hi, can you post as a new question with the html in the question making sure we can see any relevant form/frames? It is really hard to try and read this stuff in here. Where possible also share the website link (though i understand this is not always possible.). If you then put another comment here I will know there is a new question to look at.